# Kivy/KivyMD : How to reset a drop down item to its original state before the user selection

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I developed a simple app in Kivy/KivyMD/Python. The interface contains only a DropDownItem ddi and a button. The ddi displays a text, that acts as a header, and a menu with three options. Once the user selects one of the three options, the button should reset the ddi to its original state: in other words, when the button is pressed the ddi should come back as it was before the user selection, showing the text/header ('SELECT DEVICE') and removing the selection.
Here is the code

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivymd.app import MDApp

from kivymd.uix.floatlayout import MDFloatLayout
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen
from kivymd.uix.menu import MDDropdownMenu


# %% LOAD STRING
Builder.load_string(
    """        
<View>:
    MDRelativeLayout:
        padding: dp(20), dp(20), dp(20), dp(20)
        
        MDDropDownItem:
            id: ddi_device_info
            size_hint_x: None
            width: dp(100)
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.3, "center_y": 0.5}  
            on_release: root.menu_device_info.open()
            text: 'SELECT DEVICE'
            
            
        MDRaisedButton:
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.7, "center_y": 0.5}
            on_release: root.Button_Reset_DDI()
            text: 'RESET DDI'
                        
"""
)



class View(MDScreen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(View, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.menu_device_info, device_info_items = self.Create_DropDown_Widget(self.ids.ddi_device_info, ['A', 'B', 'C'], width=5)
        

    def Button_Reset_DDI(self):
        pass
        

    def Create_DropDown_Widget(self, drop_down_item, item_list, width):
        items_collection = [
            {
                "viewclass": "OneLineListItem",
                "text": item_list[i],
                "height": dp(56),
                "on_release": lambda x = item_list[i]: self.Set_DropDown_Item(drop_down_item, menu, x),
            } for i in range(len(item_list))
        ]
        
        menu = MDDropdownMenu(caller=drop_down_item, items=items_collection, width_mult=width)
        menu.bind()
        
        return menu, items_collection

         
    def Set_DropDown_Item(self, drop_down_item, menu, text_item):
        drop_down_item.set_item(text_item)
        menu.dismiss()



class MainApp(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.view = View()
        
        
    def build(self):
        self.title = 'RESET DDI'
        return self.view
           


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

What the method **Button_Reset_DDI** should contain in order to reset the ddi?

Answer (score 0):

```
def Button_Reset_DDI(self):
        self.Set_DropDown_Item(self.ids.ddi_device_info, self.menu_device_info, 'SELECT DEVICE')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def Button_Reset_DDI(self):
    self.ids.ddi_device_info.ids.label_item.text = 'SELECT DEVICE'
```